# Squid server not going to populate access.log

Tags: squid

I have configured squid on RHEL, Its working properly. Following are the directive that I have configured to populate access.log.

```
cache_access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
cache_store_log none
```

But when I check, access.log is not going to populate and does not show any data. Any idea what may be the problem ?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [sf] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
access_log daemon:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log squid
```

specify this in you squid config for generating access log information.
(/usr/local/squid/var/logs/) path depends on you custom squid folder structure